# Where is the captured image stored?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, barcode, zxing

I'm using the Xzing lib to capture barcode images, and I'm wondering where do those images get stored if there is no pre-defined or optional destination selection option?

Is the captured image just temporarily stored in the applications isolated storage untill the application terminates/ is in a closed state or what?

Comment: Actually I'd be pretty interested to learn that myself.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a quick look at [the code](http://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3bd7fb2d5eb2), it appears that image are only held in memory and it is up to you to save to IsolatedStorage if you wish to persist them that way.